# OpenCV image processing & Hough Transform: White on white background

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am currently using OpenCV with C++. I'm scanning receipts and after following the tutorial in the link given below, I am still stuck on how to proceed when the user takes a photo of the receipt on a white background (edges of receipt are TOTALLY not detected - not even close!).

https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

Screenshot sample:
[image]

Comment: Can I see a sample input picture? So that I can try in out and get back to u.

Comment: Edited question to include sample input picture. Thanks!

Comment: @user3050012 How did you solved this? Have you got a solution?